# eslint Parsing error: Unexpected token at this.setState

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, eslint

The error is like this:
[eslint Parsing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9Xuf.png)

And My code is like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'/wp-json/',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: ( data => this.setState({this.state.data : data})),
        error: ( data => console.log('Done!'))
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState parameter should be a valid object like:

```
this.setState({ key: value })
```

In your case:

```
this.setState({ data: data })
```

Also with ES6 if the key has the same name as the value, you can write:

```
this.setState({ data })
```

Comment: Thank you, it works with no errors now, you saved my day.